# collapse expand rows in section, when a section header is tapped in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I have a sectioned table view in my application, but I want to collapse / expand rows in section, when this section is tapped.

I want to know the steps how to implement.

The data is imported from JSON file as a dictinary, and I have storyboard interface builder.

I want to show/hide rows of a specific section, when this section is tapped.

I am waiting for your answer.

Comment: Have a look at [this tutorial](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/03/expandingcollapsing-tableview-sections/). There’s also [a component on GitHub](https://github.com/OliverLetterer/UIExpandableTableView).

Answer (score 0):

You can use these lines of code for this.

To add row

```
        NSIndexPath *tmpIndexpath=[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:Sender.tag];
        [tbl_Qus insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:tmpIndexpath, nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

To delete row

```
        NSIndexPath *tmpIndexpath=[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:Sender.tag];
        [tbl_Qus deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:tmpIndexpath, nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

You can download tutorial also from this [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableViewUpdates/Introduction/Intro.html).

Comment: Thank you, I will take a look at this link right now